Removing vs. clearing selected keys from a selector
As long-time developer, I have recently (finally) had to pick up Java as a language and was curious about the conventional way I see Java NIO selectors are iterated.
As pointed out on this previous question and also this duplicate one, calling select() on a selector will only add to the selected keys set, and keys must be explicitly removed after processing to indicate they have been serviced.
Most examples look something like:
while(true) {
  selector.select();
  Iterator iter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Selection key = iter.next();
    process(key);
    iter.remove();
  }
}

My question is, in the simple implementation above, where all selected keys are processed and removed, why are the keys removed on each iteration instead of all at once?
For example:
while(true) {
  selector.select();
  for(Selection key : selector.selectedKeys()) {
    process(key);
  }
  selector.selectedKeys().clear();
}

Apart from exception handling on the process step, are the two code samples equivalent? Or is there something fundamentally different about one-by-one iteration and removal vs for-loop iteration and clearing? Or is this just a matter of style and convention?

For additional clarification and reference, the documentation defines the selected-key set as:

is the set of keys such that each key's channel was detected to be
ready for at least one of the operations identified in the key's
interest set during a prior selection operation.

And furthermore, it is also explicitly noted that the only collection modification during iteration is remove(), so neither implementation would handle additional keys being added to the selected set without throwing an exception:

If the set is modified after the iterator is created, in any way
except by invoking the iterator's own remove method, then a
ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown.


@Holger I have added the relevant documentation to this question regarding when selected keys are populated. It appears to show that it's not possible for a key to be added; however, if this is the case feel free to submit your comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Good point. I normally do not take it for granted that invoking the same method twice will give you the same result (unless the documentation says it explicitly). In this case, it seems to be the case, even when the method’s documentation does not spell it out. Considering the class documentation, you’d have to use synchronized when a concurrent select is possible (in either variant), so you can indeed write the way you suggested. I would still avoid calling the method twice; var keys = selector.selectedKeys(); for(Selection key: keys) { process(key); } keys.clear(); would do.

The only advantage of using Iterator.remove, I can see, is that you can break out the loop at any time and the unprocessed keys will remain in the set.
